# SQL Query To Compare All Rows In 2 Columns

Tags: sql, database

I am tasked with creating a query that compares two columns in a table to see if the name of the schedule policy correlates with the time the backup is scheduled to run. At the moment I have come up with the only way I know how to do it and that is to have 48 select statements for the backup times like the query below. I think there may be a better or quicker way to do this, but that may exceed my knowledge about SQL queries.

SQL Query:

```
select     
    schedulePolicy, scheduleName, schedbackuptype,
    schedbackupday, schedbackupTime
from 
    commserv.dbo.CommCellBKScheduleSummary
where 
    schedulePolicy like '%00:00%' 
    and schedbackupTime not like '%00:00%'
    or schedulePolicy like '%01:00%' 
    and schedbackupTime not like '%01:00%'
```

Example Schedule Policies

Correct Schedule Policy:

```
schedulePolicy: 01_SUN_Full 00:00
schedbackupTime: 00:00
```

Incorrect Schedule Policy:

```
schedulePolicy: 01_MON_Full 00:00
schedbackTime: 02:00
```

The output for the query above should display the output below, since the backup is scheduled to run at the incorrect time.

```
schedulePolicy: 01_MON_Full 00:00 
scheduleName: Full 
schedbackuptype: Full
schedbackupday: Monday 
schedbackupTime: 02:00
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample values for the two columns.

Comment: Are you storing timestamp values as character?!? Use proper data type instead! Also tag dbms used, since many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: I edited the body of the question to put the example schedule policies into code blocks, and removed the thank you.  See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on Meta Stack Exchange for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can return rows where the time string in schedulePolicy does not match the time string in schedbackupTime, assuming that the format of schedulePolicy will always be the same:

```
SELECT schedulePolicy, scheduleName, schedbackuptype, schedbackupday, schedbackupTime
FROM commserv.dbo.CommCellBKScheduleSummary
WHERE RIGHT(schedulePolicy, 5) != schedbackupTime
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the 2 columns will never be the same. The schedPolicy is name 01_SUN_Full_01:30 and the schedbackupTime should be 01:30. I would like to parse the content of schedulePolicy to see if the backup time correlates to the schedule name.

Comment: Thanks, but this shows me schedules that are configured correctly.  I have updated what the output of the query should show, as well what the values for each key is for a correct and incorrect policy should be.  I also insert what output I expect I expect to be displayed as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do a contains the 00:00 value in schedbackupTime?